# Not null query extremely slow in ajax request partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this simple scope

```
scope :has_video_link,
        -> { where.not(video_link: nil) }
```

I use it like so in my controller

```
    @videos = Message          .featured
                               .includes(:user, :company, :forum, :topic)
                               .published
                               .unremoved
                               .approved
                               .has_video_link
                               .order(created_at: :desc)
                               .paginate(
                                 page:     page,
                                 per_page: limit)
```

Which I call like so

```
  before_action only: :index

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def index
    self.page_title = 'Home'
    fetch_videos
  end
```

That works just fine, and my page loads in under a second on prod no problem. My issue is I have an ajax request that calls this

```
  def videos
    fetch_videos

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

On dev this works great but in prod this takes over 60 seconds....
First image is from the first times its called (4ms)
2nd image is the ajax call 69000ms...
[image: First call]

[image: 2nd call]

Any ideas? How do i fix this?? Thank you!!

edit: here is the explain

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  `messages`.* FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`is_featured` = 1 AND (messages.created_at<='2021-06-04 12:36:22.241601') AND `messages`.`is_removed` = 0 AND `messages`.`is_approved` = 1 AND (`messages`.`video_link` IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY `messages`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | key                                         | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                              |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | messages | NULL       | range | index_messages_on_is_removed_and_user_id_and_created_at,index_messages_on_is_removed_and_message_type_and_created_at,index_messages_on_is_removed_company_id_type_created_at,index_messages_on_is_removed_company_id_created_at_id_user_id,index_messages_on_is_removed_and_created_at,index_messages_on_is_removed_company_id_created_at_rating_count,index_messages_on_is_removed_company_id_user_role_created_at,index_messages_on_is_removed_and_company_id_and_rating_total,index_messages_on_is_removed_and_forum_id_and_created_at,index_messages_on_is_approved,index_messages_on_is_removed_and_is_approved | index_messages_on_is_removed_and_created_at | 7       | NULL | 3470 |      9.0 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

EXPLAIN for: SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 594568
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |    100.0 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

EXPLAIN for: SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` IN (564013, 562440)
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | companies | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    2 |    100.0 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

EXPLAIN for: SELECT `forums`.* FROM `forums` WHERE `forums`.`id` IN (12224, 7759)
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | forums | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    2 |    100.0 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

EXPLAIN for: SELECT `topics`.* FROM `topics` WHERE `topics`.`id` IN (684474, 684473, 684472, 684470, 684467)
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | topics | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    5 |    100.0 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: the bottleneck maybe not the query but the rendering

Comment: I'm sure its the query.

Comment: @MohamedAli -  is not null might not be using index defined IMO. you can try explain on the query and see what indexes are being used.

Comment: @MohamedAli Could you please add the query execution plan to your question (the result of calling `explain` for your query)?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I have added the explain for the query

Comment: @AlokSwain I have added the explain for the query

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. All I had to do was simply index `video_links` and that fixed my issue right up!